# Two cordova-plugin-device plugins

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have just added the cordova plugin `com.phonegap.plugin.mobile-accessibility` to my ionic project, and it had automatically installed `cordova-plugin-device` as it is its dependency.

This would be fine, but I already have the plugin installed (as a dependancy of another plugin) under a different name (`org.apache.cordova.device`). Has anyone got any ideas on whether I should keep both, or how I could remove one.

I think that having both of these plugins is causing the following error and stopping me from building the App.

`[INFO:CONSOLE(59)] "Uncaught module cordova-plugin-device.device not found", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (59)`

I have screen dumped the dependency errors I get when trying to uninstall one of the plugins.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough fix, I removed the android platform and then re-added it again. As it went through the install it skipped the second `cordova-plugin-device` plugin install so now the platform only has it once.

The App now builds and works as it should.

Answer was found here - http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/plugins-does-not-exist/2980/5

**NOTE:** did not need to remove and add ionic & Cordova, only the Android and iOS platforms